# Open file with default program and wait until the app is terminated

Tags: kate, file-opening

I want to open a text file from the command line with the default application. During that time the default app is opened, the terminal must be disabled (cannot execute another command). For example, I use KDE and the default `.txt` reader is Kate, then I want to execute `kate test.txt` and the terminal is disabled until I terminate Kate.

What I want?

- execute a command that starts the default text editor
- meanwhile the c++ program is waiting at that specific point which executes the command described above
- when the user is ready, saves the document, exit the default text editor(terminates) and the the execution of the c++ program continues

Comment: Just open a terminal and run `kate test.txt` this is the default behavior.

Comment: I am developing project which will use this feature and I don't know which will be default text reader on another system.

Comment: Could you explain for what purpose do you need this? Often there is a better solution for common problems.

Comment: @Braiam It's the opposite: user1163511 wants to wait for the program to terminate.

Comment: If you want to do this from C++ use a call to `system()` ( `man 3 system`. Your program will continue after your editor **exits**. If you want to detect just saving you need to do something more complicated and look at `popen()` and observe the saving of the file programmatically (i.e. the program cannot just wait). BTW. This belongs on [so].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default text editor on a system is usually stored in the `$EDITOR` environmental variable. For example, on my system I have:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/emacs
```

So, you can simply run

```
$ $EDITOR test.txt
```

NOTE: This is not necessarily the same editor defined in the graphcial environment's settings. Use the method below to get that.

Alternatively, if the system is configured to use it, you can launch the default program associated with a mime type with `xdg-open` (`open` on OSX):

```
$ xdg-open test.txt
```

But that will not hold the terminal until the command closes. However, you can use the mime setup to find out what program *would* be opened and then call the program yourself. To do this, get the program associated with the text mime type:

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
pluma.desktop;sublime_text.desktop
```

So, now you can parse that line to get the program name:

```
editor=$(xdg-mime query default text/plain | sed 's/\..*//')
$editor test.txt
```

NOTE: This assumes that the `.desktop` file has the name of the actual executable. A safer way might be to locate the desktop file itself and grep the executable from it. Then, launch the program you found. You can do the whole thing with this command:

```
editor=$(grep -i ^exec $(locate -n 1 $(xdg-mime query default text/plain |
                        cut -d';' -f 1)) | 
           perl -pe 's/.*=(\S+).*/$1/') 
$editor test.txt
```